# Matlab, Openface, FaceLandmarkImg versions problems (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: matlab

I try to run a matlab script that uses FaceLandmarkImg and I get these messages (I replaced my username by "user") :

```
/home/user/Documents/OpenFace/build/bin/FaceLandmarkImg: /home/user/Documents/bin/glnxa64/libtiff.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/user/Documents/OpenFace/build/bin/FaceLandmarkImg)
/home/user/Documents/OpenFace/build/bin/FaceLandmarkImg: libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/user/Documents/OpenFace/build/bin/FaceLandmarkImg) /home/user/Documents/OpenFace/build/bin/FaceLandmarkImg: libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0)
/home/user/Documents/OpenFace/build/bin/FaceLandmarkImg: libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0) /home/user/Documents/OpenFace/build/bin/FaceLandmarkImg: libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so.1)
```

I installed the newest versions of `ghostscript-9.24`, `libstdc++.so.6` and I checked that I have `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` (indeed I have it).

I think it could be a problem of path or directory but I don't know how to fix it.

I'm very new at using Linux, Matlab and even more OpenFace so my question may seem stupid... Sorry for that !

Any answer is welcome !

Answer (score 1):

I did

```
LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5" ./matlab
```

and it worked.

More explanations:
It looks like matlab was unable to find these two needed libraries: libstdc++.so.6 and libtiff.so.5
The command above "launches" these two libraries before launching matlab. So now matlab is able to find them. 
I think an other way to avoid my problem was to specify to matlab the way to find theses libraries but I have not been able to do that.